# Sort Array but keep row indexes

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a array like this:

names, state, houseprice, carsprice

john,  WI,    200,        100
jimmy, MI,    100,        90
...

How do I sort the houseprice and car price without changing the elements in that same row? Like sort the whole row of "john" based on their houseprice and carprice against another row in the array but keep everything in the row together.

this is what I have so far,

```
for (int i=0;getline(file,(names[i]),',');i++)
{ 
getline(file, states[i], ',');

getline(file, houseprice[i], ',') ;

getline(file, carprice[i]); 
}
```

how I want to sort houseprice and carprice against another row without losing the name and states along with that row.

Comment: C++ , please I need help.

Comment: Don't use separate arrays for each column, but a `vector` of an aggregate type, and sort it with `std::sort` with a custom comparator.

Answer (score 0):

Just project the field you are interested in as part of your comparison function object but otherwise treat the objects as one unit:

```
house array[] = { ... };
// sort by houseprice; similar for other attributes:
std::sort(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [](house const& h0, house const& h1) {
              return h0.houseprice < h1.houseprice;
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to implement a vector that maps "original" order to the "sorted" order,

so the sort algorithm result will be a mapping vector and the function that draws the output table need to draw it by the order of the mapping vector.
for example, if after sorting all lines stay on first order position and only lines 4,5 swap

places the mapping vector will be:
Index: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
Data : 0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7, ...

since your question is quite general - so does the answer

Comment: Ummm....I haven't been taught how to use struct, I just need to sort the houseprice and carprice against another houseprice and carprice from high to low but I have to make sure that the elements of name and state tag along while sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a vector of struct 
eg:

```
struct PersonalInfo
{
  string name;
  string state;
  int housePriceCents;
  int carPriceCents;
}

std::vector<PersonalInfo> infos;
```

Then use sort with a compare function passed in, or define the < operator in your struct, so that structs with lower prices are considered less than structs with higher prices.